# How to detect if running inside Windows Metro application process?

Tags: c++, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am developing a library and I would like to be able to detect if it is running inside Metro style application to selectively disable/enable some functionality. Is it possible?

Comment: This type of question is common, the answer always the same.  The application has no trouble at all telling you that it is a Metro app.  So just let it tell you.  Always easier than trying to deal with a linker error or a runtime fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`IMetroMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404160%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface to check if your library has been loaded inside a Metro-style application. Call the [`GetMonitorMode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404165%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method, if `pMode` will hold `MMM_METRO` then you'll be sure you're running inside a Metro application.

Comment: Probably good, but since it's not available in versions lower than 8, won't use of it cause errors when on those older versions?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg of course, he has to check Windows version before try to create an instance of that interface (and if not available in that case he's sure he's not running on Metro...)

Comment: @Adriano: Actually, it might not work (untested). The documentation says "Applies to: desktop apps only". Does that not mean that I would not be able to actually get the interface in Metro style application?

Comment: @wilx no, "desktop apps only" indicates that it does not apply to web applications. I hope someday Microsoft will change that sentence to something more understandable...

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: `IMetroMode` is a COM interface. Querying for it can cause a runtime error, but precisely that error signals the absence of Metro.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple test:

```
if (WinJS) {
    // WinJS exists in global if in WinRT app
}
```